# Showing that two maps are injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and $M$ a left $R-$module. The module $M$ is said to be uniserial if the poset of submodules of $M$ is a chain. Let $M$ be a  uniserial module and $\alpha,\beta\in End_R(M)$.

> Why we have:  $\alpha\beta$ is injective if and only if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are injective.
>   Thanks in advance

Comment: Was also addressed at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2638409/29335  in the comments to the solution, and was possibly the same poster using a different name.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is obvious: if $\alpha, \beta$ are injective, so is $\alpha \beta$.

Hint for the other: "$\alpha \beta$ is injective" means in particular that $\beta$ is injective, so the question is whether $\alpha$ is injective as well. But look at the submodules $\mathrm{Ker}\, \alpha, \mathrm{Im}\, \beta:$ One has to have one in the other by uniseriality. Use this to show that we necessarily have $\mathrm{Ker}\, \alpha=0$.

Comment: Please can you give more details ?                                                      
Thanks

Comment: since $M$ is uniserial, either $ker(\alpha)⊆Im(\beta)$ or $Im(\beta)⊆ker(\alpha)$. The first case is obviously impossible when $M$ is nonzero and $\alpha\beta$ is injective. But i don't find a contradiction, would you please help me