# Surjective endomorphisms of uniserial modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Please help me to prove the following result:

Let   $R$  be  a ring with $1$ and $M$ a uniserial left $R-$module and $\alpha,\beta\in End_R(M)$.

> $\alpha\beta$ is surjective if and only if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are surjective

This is what i wrote:

The implication 
if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are surjective then $\alpha\beta$ is surjective is evident since the composition of two surjective functions is surjective:

Let $\alpha:M \to M$ and $\beta:M \to M$ be surjective functions.

We wish to show that $\alpha\circ \beta:M \to M$ is also surjective.

Now, we know that for every $c \in M$, there is a $b \in M$ such that $c = \alpha(b)$, by surjectivity of $\alpha$. And we know that for that same $b$, there exists an $a \in M$ such that $b=\beta(a)$, by surjectivity of $\beta$.

So what we have shown is that for every $c \in M$, there is an $a \in M$ such that $c=\alpha(\beta(a))=\alpha \circ \beta(a)$, i.e., $\alpha \circ \beta$ is surjective.

For the other inmplication let us suppose that $\alpha\beta$ is surjective. Let $a\in M$ by sujectivity of $\alpha\beta$ there exist $b\in M$ such that $\alpha\beta(b)=a$ hence there exist $c=\beta(b)\in M$ such that $\alpha(c)=a$ then $\alpha$ is surjective

But i am not able to prove that $\beta$ is also surjective. Please help me to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice to see a post with good context for a change. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Although your title and tag were pretty poor. Never title a question "question about [some tag]." Be more specific.  Who would go see the movie "Titanic" if it were titled "A movie about a ship"? And always put a more specific on top of [abstract-algebra]

Comment: ok i will consider that

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the uniserial condition this way: since $M$ is uniserial, either $\ker(\alpha)\subseteq Im(\beta)$ or $Im(\beta)\subseteq \ker(\alpha)$. The latter case is obviously impossible when $M$ is nonzero and $\alpha\beta$ is surjective.

Now suppose $x\notin Im(\beta)$.

As you've already seen, there exists $b\in M$ such that $\alpha(\beta(b))=\alpha(x)$.

That means $\beta(b)-x\in \ker(\alpha)$.

So $\beta(b)-x\in\ker(\alpha)\subseteq Im(\beta)$. But this implies $x\in Im(\beta)$, a contradiction.

Therefore $\beta$ must be surjective.

Comment: And for the implication $\alpha\beta$ injective imply $\alpha$ injective can i answer like following:since $M$ is uniserial, either $\ker(\alpha)\subseteq Im(\beta)$ or $Im(\beta)\subseteq \ker(\alpha)$. The first case is obviously impossible when $M$ is nonzero and $\alpha\beta$ is injective.

But i don' find a contradiction, would you please help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: We suppose there exist a non zero $x\in ker(\alpha)$  then 

$\alpha(x)=0$.

I don't know how to continue ??

Comment: @aymen No, the *second* case is the impossible one.  The first containment has to happen, for example, when the kernel is zero. Try using the other containment.

Comment: So if there exist a non zero $x∈ker(α)$ then $x\in Im(\beta)$ and where is the contradiction?

Comment: @aymen  $x=\beta( y)$ and then $0=\alpha(x)=\alpha\beta(x)$. See it now?

Comment: if $kef (\alpha)=0\subset Im(\beta)$ how to use that? we have $\beta(0)=0$

Comment: @aymen $\beta(0)=0$ for *any* linear map. We have something stronger: $\beta(x)=0\implies x=0$. Also, you dno't have that $\ker(f)=\{0\}$. That's what we're trying to prove. I'm just saying that eventually we will prove $\ker(\alpha)=\{0\}\subseteq Im(\beta)$.

Comment: Ok i will write the full answer and please correct it for me:  the implication $αβ$ injective imply $α$ injective: since $M$ is uniserial, either $ker(α)⊆Im(β)$ or $Im(β)⊆ker(α)$. The  latter case is obviously impossible when M is nonzero and $αβ$ is injective. Let $x\in ker(\alpha)$ then $x\in Im(\beta)$ them there exists $y\in M$ such that $x=\beta( y)$ and then 0=\alpha(x)=\alpha\beta(x), hence $x\in ker(\alpha\beta)$ thus $ker(\alpha)\subset ker(\alpha\beta)=\left\{0\right\}$

Comment: @aymen Looks good